# Android (Gingerbread): Slide out SupportMapFragment hides map during animation

Tags: android, google-maps, android-animation

[image]

As shown in the picture above, I want to slide out `LayoutA` which is a google maps `SupportMapFragment`, to show some Settings in `LayoutB`

I achieve this with `translationX()` on LayoutA, which is only working in API11+. However, I found a work-around using a `TranslationAnimation` in API10, but the map itself is hidden while the animation is running. The buttons of the `MapFragement` for currentPosition and ZoomIn/ZoomOut are shown as expected, but the map itself hides at the beginning of the `TranslationAnimation`, and is shown again, if the Animation is over.

This is the layout of the Fragment (The Map is within a Relative Layout, and I change the position of the Relative Layout)

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

  //LAYOUT B
  <RelativeLayout  
    android:id="@+id/back_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


  //LAYOUT A
  <RelativeLayout           
    android:id="@+id/front_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_screen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/map_screen_bottom_bar"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">
    </fragment>
```

And my Animation

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1) {
((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.front_frame)).animate()
    .translationX(-1 * mScreenWidth);
} else {

TranslateAnimation slideOut = new TranslateAnimation(0, -1
    * mScreenWidth, 0, 0);
slideOut.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(
    R.integer.animation_transistion_length_short));
slideOut.setFillEnabled(true);
//slideOut.setFillAfter(true);

slideOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}


    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}


    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        RelativeLayout mView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.front_frame);
        int[] pos = { mView.getLeft() - mScreenWidth,
            mView.getTop(), mView.getRight(),
            mView.getBottom() };

        mView.layout(pos[0], pos[1], pos[2], pos[3]);

    }
});

((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.front_frame))
    .startAnimation(slideOut);
```

}

here s a bad picture of it, taken during the animation. the buttons for location and zoom are animated. the map itself isn't shown but appears, if the animation is over. Anyone any ideas?  [image]